# DataURI with XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, openlayers, data-uri

Is it possible to use a DataURI instead of a URL in an XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) call so it's not really going over the wire rather using data that's already in the client? I'm going to experiment with it, but I wanted to see if anyone has done something like that or if it's even possible. Thanks!

**Context:**
My use case is to work around a problem I'm facing in OpenLayers where they expect a URL, but I have the data on the client already and want to load it directly since it's a large file.

Comment: you can in most browsers, but there are better ways of getting at the data. use window.URL instead for better performance without cross-domain issues...

Comment: I don't understand how I'll run into cross-domain issues? The data is already in the browser session.

Comment: data: is a different prototocol than http, and data: cannot emit cors headers. i believe CSPs can affect this allowance as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer here is that you cannot use DataURI with XmlHttpRequest. As pointed by @dandavis above, it is a different protocol.